# Download a Linkedin Page

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, async-await, linkedin-api

If I try to download any other page i can. However if I try to download a specific LinkedIn page it prints bunch of JavaScript.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/profile/'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

result:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  // Parse the tracking code from cookies.
  var trk = "bf";
  var trkInfo = "bf";
  var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
    if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkCode=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
      trk = cookies[i].substring(8);
    }
    else if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkInfo=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
      trkInfo = cookies[i].substring(8);
    }
  }

  if (window.location.protocol == "http:") {
    // If "sl" cookie is set, redirect to https.
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
      if ((cookies[i].indexOf("sl=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 3)) {
        window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  // Get the new domain. For international domains such as
  // fr.linkedin.com, we convert it to www.linkedin.com
  var domain = "www.linkedin.com";
  if (domain != location.host) {
    var subdomainIndex = location.host.indexOf(".linkedin");
    if (subdomainIndex != -1) {
      domain = "www" + location.host.substring(subdomainIndex);
    }
  }

  window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/authwall?trk=" + trk + "&trkInfo=" + trkInfo +
      "&originalReferer=" + document.referrer.substr(0, 200) +
      "&sessionRedirect=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
}
</script>
</head></html>
```

I guess it is related with `async` load. But i couldn't figure out how to download the page.

Comment: You may want to use selenium

Comment: @PedroLobito I don't want browser intervention.

Comment: Being so, no luck for you in this case.

Comment: You need to be logged in to see this page. The code you're receiving here is the one redirecting you to the login page.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: open an "incognito" or "private" window in your web browser. Try to go to a specific LinkedIn page. You'll be redirected to log in. **You can only access a LinkedIn profile if you are logged in.**

How does this work? When LinkedIn receives a request, it looks for a specific cookie called `li_at` in the request. If it does not find this cookie, it redirects the requester to a page with the JavaScript you had. This JavaScript serves to redirect you to the login page. That's what all the `window.location.href=` stuff is about.

**You can "fake" a logged-in request** by going to LinkedIn, copying your own `li_at` cookie, and adding that to your request. Note that this will only work temporarily: at some point LinkedIn will expect that cookie to change, and you will have to re-copy it.

You can find the cookie in the Chrome developer tools:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome developer tools]

For example:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/robertakarobin/', headers={
    'cookie': 'li_at=abc123'
})
print(response.content)
```

Or, in the shell:

```
curl -H "cookie: li_at=abc123" -i https://www.linkedin.com/in/robertakarobin/
```